# Can I iterate through SqlDataReader. And use it to display it's values in single textbox one after another

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am using code as follows:

```
Button1_Click() 
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    Command = "select country from customer";

    Con.open();

    While (dr.read())
    {
         Textbox1.text = dr.toValues(0);
    }
}
```

I want to display each country in textbox1 one after another. In each button click.

Comment: Can you give some details on what goes wrong when you run your code, and what input data you provide it.

Comment: So...with each new click you show a different country in the textbox?  The next one in line so to speak?  Or are you looking for all the countries to show up in the textbox at the same time, like a list?

Comment: You do not want to iterate through your sql reader in this way.  Get your list from the database and put it into a variable.  Then as your user interacts with the UI invoke your code that populates your text box with the next value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this ;

```
 Textbox1.text =Textbox1.text + "," + dr.toValues(0);
```

**Note : If you are running the `DataReader` in a background thread , you won't be able to access any UI element.In that case,you might require a variable**

```
string result;

While (dr.read())
{
 result = result + "," + dr.ToValue(0) /// tovalue is also unnecessary, you should rather use :

result = result + "," + dr(0) /// you can use .ToString if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate variable and then set that to the textbox.

```
string result = string.empty

While (dr.read())
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
    {
        result = dr.GetString(0);
    }
    else
    {
        result = result  + ", " + dr.GetString(0);
    }
}

Textbox1.text = result;
```

Comment: `string result` will have no value by default,it isn't needed to set `string.empty` as it's value , moreover u missed `;` in the first line too..And using a variable and then passing it to a textbox is just not worth it...I'll be glad if you edit your answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I made you all little bit confused:
I am trying to say that when we first click the button then first country will be display in the textbox, thereafter when we again click the same button then the first country must be completely disappear from the textbox and it's place should be taken by next country(i.e. next row) and so on.

Comment: sorry, I made you all little bit confused: I am trying to say that when we first click the button then first country will be display in the textbox, thereafter when we again click the same button then the first country must be completely disappear from the textbox and it's place should be taken by next country(i.e. next row) and so on.